# Deploying SQLite database to Android with Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am trying to deploy an application to run on the android emulator using delphi that uses an SQLite database and populates a combobox with the query results.

I Have tested all the code on a Win32 application and everything is working as intended, however when i deploy the SQLite database and try to run the application on the emulator i raise an exception with "TDBXError with message" and the ErrorMessage contains 'no such table: cars'

Below is the code for my form.

```
    var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Populate Manufacturer box
  SQLConnection1.Connected := True;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.Close;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT DISTINCT manufacturer FROM cars');
  try
    SQLQuery1.Open;
    cbManufac.Items.Clear;
    while not SQLQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      cbManufac.Items.Add(SQLQuery1.Fields[0].AsString);
      SQLQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    SQLQuery1.Close;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SQLConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['ColumnMetadataSupported'] := 'False';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] :=
      System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'cars.sqlite');
  {$ENDIF}
end;

end.
```

I Have made sure System.IOUtils is added to uses and my database file is added under my projects deployment settings.

If i activate Win32 and test the application the combobox entries are added just fine.

On the form designer i am using TSQLConnection and TSQLQuery

Can anybody point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the Deployment Manager, set your remote path for your database to `assets\external`. (See the [documentation here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files) for the difference between `assets\internal` and `assets\external`.)

Change your `BeforeConnect` event code to:

```
procedure TForm1.SQLConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['ColumnMetadataSupported'] := 'False';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] :=
      TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'cars.sqlite');
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

To see the physical location of `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath` and other locations, see [Standard RTL Path Functions Across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms).

Comment: I have made edit with assets\external, because it's fail, and you remove my changes again.